# Android DownloadManager not working (PAUSED_UNKNOWN) in API 16 to 19

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Using the following code snippet:

```
try {
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse((url + "?sid=" + sessionId)));
    String filename = itemId + ".pkpass";
    File downloadDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setDescription(getString(R.string.item_description_download));
    request.setTitle(filename);
    request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadDir, filename)));
    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", System.getProperty("http.agent") + " my_app/" + Utils.appVersionNumber());
    downloadId = dManager.enqueue(request);

    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
    query.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.PAUSED_UNKNOWN);
    Cursor c = dManager.query(query);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int status = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
        if (status == DownloadManager.PAUSED_UNKNOWN) {
            // Occurs when using Android API 16 to 19
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    showToast(getString(R.string.item_download_error));
}
```

API 21 (Android 5.0) + works just fine. No problems there.

Now, when I'm using Android API 16 (Android 4.1-4.1.1) to API 19 it will not download the file, only stay in an endless "downloading loop" with state `PAUSED_UNKNOWN`.

Anyone knows this problem?

Permissions are also given...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
```

Gradle:

```
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
   minSdkVersion 16
   targetSdkVersion 21
```